# window online event listener not being called

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to check if the user is offline or online in my Vue app, but the online and offline event listeners only get called when the user changes their connection status. Is there a way to fire the event listener to check if the user is online or offline when the component is mounted?

I have tried to use watchEffect to see if I could fire it, but think I have missed something.

I'm trying to check to see if the user is online or offline before either making an API call or to grab a value from local storage.

```html
<script setup>

import { ref, onMounted, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const isOnline = ref(false);

const updateOnlineStatus = (e) => console.log(navigator.onLine);

watchEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('online', updateOnlineStatus);
    window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
})

onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('online', updateOnlineStatus);
    window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});

<script>
```

Comment: `onMounted(() => updateOnlineStatus())`. But probably can be done outside onMounted because it's not tied to dom. And you're not changing isOnline anywhere.

Comment: Yes i took the change out and swapped for a console log just to see its was firing! thank you, thats worked brilliantly!